# Auto Suggest / Auto complete not working - Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, solr-query-syntax, solr-schema

I am using SOLR autocomplete feature. But it's not working for "oral" keyword.

Below are field details from schema -

```
<field name="text_autocomplete" type="text_auto" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>        
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
<field name="ProductName" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="ProductNameAssigned" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<copyField source="ProductName" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="ProductNameAssigned" dest="text_autocomplete"/>
```

Why autosuggest is not displaying "oral" when i type "ora" ??
i am able to return result for same keyword "oral". 
Please suggest.

Comment: How are you searching? What's the query? Which endpoint?

Comment: Please share your solr query as well so people can help.

Comment: Please see below query
 http://localhost:8983/solr/entity-1/suggest?spellcheck.q=ora

I have hosted solr on local machine

Comment: Autosuggest is working for keyword "Orange" but not working for  "Oral" or "Oralb"

Comment: Any help ?? Still having same issue